# Create SQL database

Tags: sql, database, azure, visual-studio-2012

I am following this tutorial http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2010/03/24/how-to-use-asp-net-forms-auth-with-sql-server.aspx and I am stuck on step 6 where I have to set up the membership database. I have opened the aspnet_regsql wizard but the setup is failing with errors such as:

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

Does anyone know what I can do? I am a beginner with SQL and I am not sure if I have the right program installed although it seems that I have an SQLExpress instance running on my PC.

I am using Windows 8 with Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web for the tutorial.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change the connection string to point to your machine.

Since you are using express it is most likely as below.

```
connectionString="Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

Not that i've replaced `MyServerName` with `localhost\sqlexpress`

Comment: Is that all I have to do though? I have not created any database yet. I am also still getting the same errors when running the ASP.NET SQL Server Setup Wizard.

Comment: I have managed to create the database by entering my server name with \SQLEXPRESS appended to it like so:  ANDROMEDA\SQLEXPRESS.

I now have another problem. When I run the project, I get an error:
 'the page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred'

Any ideas how I can fix this error?